pickadate plugin is not working as it is always showing wrong date in the dropdown calendar
I have the Calendar dates setup, i have two input fields and both carry dates and input fields values are coming Like this
There is the fiddle I created
https://jsfiddle.net/v67ex84t/
<input type="text" class="form-control" class="igameDate" id="gameDate2" name="gamedate2" data-value="12/25/2023" value="12/25/2023"/> 

<input type="text" class="form-control" class="igameDate" id="gameDate3" name="gamedate1" data-value='12/25/2023' value="12/25/2023" /> 

I have the following Js code
var picker1 = $('#gameDate2').pickadate({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    selectYears: true,
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: true,
    selectMonths: true,
    disable: [
        true,
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 2, 21],
        [2023, 3, 21],
        [2023, 3, 21],
        [2023, 3, 21],
        [2023, 3, 22],
        [2023, 4, 1],
        [2023, 4, 12],
        [2023, 4, 21],
        [2023, 4, 21],
        [2023, 4, 21],
        [2023, 4, 21]
    ],
    'min': "12/23/2023",
    'max': "05/21/2024",
    klass: {
        infocus: 'picker__day--enabled',
        highlighted: 'picker__day--outfocus'
    },
    today: '',
    clear: '',
    close: '',
    onSet: function(event) {
        var selectedDate = event.select;
        if (selectedDate === undefined) {
            selectedDate = Date.now();
        }
        if (typeof selectedDate == "number") {
            selectedDate = unixDateTOString(selectedDate);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'schedule_getgame.cfm?gamedate=' + selectedDate + '&clientID=' + '1111',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    var $jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $gameSelect.html('');
                    if ($jsonObject.length === 0) {
                        $gameSelect.prop("disabled", true);
                        $color.css('display', 'none');
                    } else {
                        $gameSelect.prop("disabled", false);
                        $color.css('display', 'inline-block');
                        $gameSelect.append('<option value="">Please select Game ......</option>');
                        $.each($jsonObject, function(index, item) {
                            if (typeof gameIdJs !== 'undefined' && gameIdJs == item.gameID) {
                                $gameSelect.append("<option selected value='" + item.gameID + "-" + item.clientID + "-" + item.gameNumber + "-" + item.gameDate + "-" + item.gameTime + "-" + item.homeTeam + "-" + item.awayTeam + "'>" + 'Game ' + item.gameNumber + " on " + item.gameDate + " at " + item.gameTime + " between " + item.homeTeam + " and " + item.awayTeam + "</option>");
                            } else {
                                $gameSelect.append("<option value='" + item.gameID + "-" + item.clientID + "-" + item.gameNumber + "-" + item.gameDate + "-" + item.gameTime + "-" + item.homeTeam + "-" + item.awayTeam + "'>" + 'Game ' + item.gameNumber + " on " + item.gameDate + " at " + item.gameTime + " between " + item.homeTeam + " and " + item.awayTeam + "</option>");
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}).pickadate('picker');
if (gameDateJs !== 0) {
    $('#gameDate2').val(gameDateJs);
    picker1.set('select', gameDateJs, {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
}
var picker2 = $('#gameDate3').pickadate({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    selectYears: true,
    selectMonths: true,
    selectYears: true,
    selectMonths: true,
    disable: [
        true,
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 23],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 24],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 25],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 26],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2023, 11, 27],
        [2024, 2, 21],
        [2024, 3, 21],
        [2024, 3, 21],
        [2024, 3, 21],
        [2024, 3, 22],
        [2024, 4, 1],
        [2024, 4, 12],
        [2024, 4, 21],
        [2024, 4, 21],
        [2024, 4, 21],
        [2024, 4, 21]
    ],
    'min': "12/23/2023",
    'max': "05/21/2024",
    klass: {
        infocus: 'picker__day--enabled',
        highlighted: 'picker__day--outfocus'
    },
    today: '',
    clear: '',
    close: '',
    onSet: function(event) {
        var selectedDate = event.select;
        if (selectedDate === undefined) {
            selectedDate = Date.now();
        }
        if (typeof selectedDate == "number") {
            selectedDate = unixDateTOString(selectedDate);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'schedule_getgame.cfm?gamedate=' + selectedDate + '&clientID=' + '1111',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    var $jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $gameSelectAway.html('');
                    if ($jsonObject.length === 0) {
                        $gameSelectAway.prop("disabled", true);
                        $color1.css('display', 'none');
                    } else {
                        $gameSelectAway.prop("disabled", false);
                        $color1.css('display', 'inline-block');
                        $gameSelectAway.append('<option value="">Please select Game ......</option>');
                        $.each($jsonObject, function(index, item) {
                            if (typeof gameIdJsAway !== 'undefined' && gameIdJsAway == item.gameID) {
                                $gameSelectAway.append("<option selected value='" + item.gameID + "-" + item.clientID + "-" + item.gameNumber + "-" + item.gameDate + "-" + item.gameTime + "-" + item.homeTeam + "-" + item.awayTeam + "'>" + 'Game ' + item.gameNumber + " on " + item.gameDate + " at " + item.gameTime + " between " + item.homeTeam + " and " + item.awayTeam + "</option>");
                            } else {
                                $gameSelectAway.append("<option value='" + item.gameID + "-" + item.clientID + "-" + item.gameNumber + "-" + item.gameDate + "-" + item.gameTime + "-" + item.homeTeam + "-" + item.awayTeam + "'>" + 'Game ' + item.gameNumber + " on " + item.gameDate + " at " + item.gameTime + " between " + item.homeTeam + " and " + item.awayTeam + "</option>");
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}).pickadate('picker');
if (gameDateJsAway !== 0) {
    picker2.set('select', gameDateJsAway, {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
}

function unixDateTOString(unix_timestamp) {
    var dateObj = new Date(unix_timestamp);
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    var month = dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
    var date = dateObj.getDate();
    var formattedTime = date + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    return formattedTime;
}

now it works but what hapens is, when i select the date and from the dropdown it shows dec 2023 but 27 selected and in the second calendar dropdown using piakdate it shows a totaly different date
i am getting lost in this code what is going wrong here
code is updated as above

Please create a fiddle to reproduce the issues.

here is the Created Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v67ex84t/
